# Watin browser title property is empty

Tags: asp.net-mvc, watin, specflow

I'm using Watin with Specflow on an mvc3 web app. I've setup a helper to create a static browser to use for my step test methods. All appears to be set up correctly, however when I run my test, the browser title property is empty on the assertion (my "Then" method). I've also tried searching for elements on the page and a browser just ends up timing out.

I've tried debugging but that does not seem to help either since the browser is static.

What else could be causing this?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

BTY- the browser opens and navigates to the page I requested on the first step.

**Update:**

I created another app to try to pin point the problem...same issue.  Code is shown below.

App.Config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="NUnit">
            <section name="TestRunner" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler"/>
        </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>
    <NUnit>
        <TestRunner>
            <!-- Valid values are STA,MTA. Others ignored. -->
            <add key="ApartmentState" value="STA" />
        </TestRunner>
    </NUnit>
</configuration>
```

Specflow Feature

```
Feature: TestMyWebApp
In order to test my web app
As a user
I want to navigate to the home page

@mytag
Scenario: Navigation to homepage
When I navigate to /Home
Then I should be on the home page
```

Step File

```
[Binding]
public class TestMyWebAppSteps
{
    [When(@"I navigate to /Home")]
    public void WhenINavigateToHome()
    {
        WebBrowser.Current.GoTo("http://localhost:57556/Home");
    }


    [Then(@"I should be on the home page")]
    public void ThenIShouldBeOnTheHomePage()
    {
        Assert.AreEqual("Home", WebBrowser.Current.Title);
    }
}
```

Browser helper

```
public static class WebBrowser
{
    public static IE Current
    {
        get
        {
            string key = "browser";
            if (!ScenarioContext.Current.ContainsKey(key))
            {
                ScenarioContext.Current[key] = new IE();
            }
            return ScenarioContext.Current[key] as IE;
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas how I can pinpoint the problem???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was due to IE9 running in protected mode for Internet Sites =\

[WatiN BrowserNotFoundException after upgrading to IE9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9999480/watin-browsernotfoundexception-after-upgrading-to-ie9)

HTH